# Ajax form submission with file upload not working Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Ajax code:

```
var str = $("#observationForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        data : str,
        url : "updateObservation",
        async : true,
/* dataType : "multipart/form-data", */
        success : function() {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
```

JSP-Spring Form :

```
<form:form modelAttribute="ObservationModal" action="updateObservation" id="observationForm">
    <label class="control-label">Tooth No</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tooth" id="tooth" placeholder="Enter tooth no" />
    <label class="control-label">Uploaded file(PDF)</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="attachment" value="" id="attachment" placeholder="" />        
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="updateObservation();" />
</form:form>
```

Controller Class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateObservation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updateObservation(
        @ModelAttribute("ObservationModal") ObservationModal formObj) {
    String result = "";

    System.out.println(":" + formObj.getTooth());
    System.out.println(formObj.getAttachment());

    return result;
}
```

Modal Class

```
public class ObservationModal implements Serializable {
    int tooth;
    private List<MultipartFile> attachment;

    public int getTooth() {
        return tooth;
    }

    public void setTooth(int tooth) {
        this.tooth = tooth;
    }

    public List<MultipartFile> getAttachment() {
        return attachment;
    }

    public void setAttachment(List<MultipartFile> attachment) {
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }

}
```

I can't get the values textbox values or attachment in controller. The ObservationModal is always null

Answer (score 1):

To make the ajax call the url must be of the type '/projectName/actualurl'. In your case url:'/projectName/updateObservation'. And also add dataType:'text' to the call.

Answer (score 1):

A file cannot be uploaded using AJAX. To make it happen 
you can use formdata for fileupload but this work for only html5 supported browsers

```
var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standart javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

And if you want it to work even for older browsers you can use iframe with form for fileupload.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading a file normally you need to use `encType="multipart/form-data"` in your form.
If you want to use Ajax to upload a file, Along with Simple ajax call you need to use its fileupload plugin.
For more details have a look here: [Link1](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/), [Link2](http://www.technicaladvices.com/2011/12/10/ajax-file-upload-to-a-java-servlet-in-html5/), [Link 3](http://javasantoshanand.blogspot.in/2013/08/using-ajax-jquery-and-servlet-to-upload.html),
[Link 4](http://tuts.wtfdiary.com/2013/02/dynamic-file-upload-ajax-jsp.html)

Comment: Did you use fileupload plugin for ajax? Follow the given links.